# Combining Multiple if into one?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two wordpress queries and am curious if there is a way to combine them into one?
I have tried else if, but to no avail.

```
<?php 
$posts = get_field('appeal_forms', 'options');
if( $posts ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And here the second:

```
 <?php 
    $posts = get_field('misc', 'options');
    if( $posts ): ?>
        <ul>
        <?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
            <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: are you missing some of your code?

Comment: So which 2 queries do you want to combine?

Comment: Apologies, corrected

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you hoping will be possible? Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine both arrays of posts into a single array then loop through it as you were doing.

In the example below I'm getting both arrays, checking they are valid using `is_array` and then merging them into one using `array_merge`.

```
<?php
// Get both post arrays.
$appeal_forms = get_field('appeal_forms', 'options');
$misc         = get_field('misc', 'options');

// Check both are arrays.
if ( is_array( $appeal_forms ) && is_array( $misc ) ) { 
    // Combine the posts into a single array.
    $posts = array_merge( $appeal_forms, $misc ); ?>

    <ul>
        <?php foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

If both arrays won't always have posts then the code needs to be adapted. The check I perform means that if appeal_forms or misc is empty then nothing is displayed.

If that's the case the solution I'd propose would be:

```
$posts = array();

// Check each array individually and add their contents to the post array.
if ( is_array( $appeal_forms ) ) {
    $posts = array_merge( $posts, $appeal_forms );
}

if ( is_array( $misc ) ) {
    $posts = array_merge( $posts, $misc );
}

if ( $posts ) {…
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, appreciate it!. Looks like there is a syntax error in the if, but not sure what. ALso, would this merge the results or still separate them out?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was coding on the fly and missed a closing bracket in the if statement. All the results will be merged.

Comment: I actually didn't know what it was... :) ha! Thanks for letting me know what it was. One last thing, as am still learning, how would one keep the results still separate?